# Saving ArrayList<Uri> to SharedPreferences

Tags: java, android, sharedpreferences

I create a few ArrayLists during one of my activities. When I leave the activity and come back to it, they come up as null. From some research, SharedPreferences is the way to overcome this. How do I go about this; do I have to save it as a HashMap? is SharedPreferences it's own method or do I do it within another specific method?

Comment: You should check if `tempSet` is `null` before trying to use it. Same goes for `temp2Set`. Also, it appears that both lists have the same contents. Is there a reason you are doing this?

Comment: @Code-Apprentice that's what I ended up doing. This code just served as an example close to my code which might be why some of it is redundant. I'll post my solution.

Comment: Please do not edit your question such that it invalidates existing answers. Instead, create a new question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

** you have convert this array to gson.

** First pass your array in parameter public void saveArrayList(ArrayList list, String key)

** now create object of SharedPreferences

```
SharedPreferences prefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(activity);
SharedPreferences.Editor editor = prefs.edit();
```

** now convert to gson :

```
Gson gson = new Gson();
String json = gson.toJson(list);
editor.putString(key, json);
editor.apply();     // This line is IMPORTANT !!!
```

Answer (score 1):

You have at least three options:

1. Use a SharedPreferences *object* as you suggest in your question.
2. Use a SQLite database.
3. Use a file with your own format.

For an introduction to each of these options, read [Storage Options](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html).

Comment: One thing I'd like to recommend in addition to this is a very nice to use class that uses SharedPreferences and it's very easy to use also: https://github.com/kcochibili/TinyDB--Android-Shared-Preferences-Turbo, you can do stuff like `tinydb.putListObject("list", new ArrayList<URI>());`

Comment: Thanks for point me to the introduction. I think SharedPreferences is the way to go for me. Still not sure how to pass my URI lists to it and call them back though, as my original question suggests

Comment: @ImagineThat After you read the documentation for `SharedPreferences` and try a few things, feel free to come back with more questions, the more specific the better.

Comment: @Code-Apprentice Thanks for the suggestion. I did more research and have now specified my question with my code. Please take a look.

Answer (score 1):

Here, how to write on **Shared Preferences**:

```
    SharedPreferences sp = getActivity().getPreferences(Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    //if your codes in your activity class, you dont need getActivity so you should use this
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sp.edit();
    editor.putInt("your_string_key", yourValue);
    editor.commit();
```

Here, how to read from **Shared Preferences**:

```
SharedPreferences sp = getActivity().getPreferences(Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
//same here. If your codes in your activity don't write "getActivity." part
int yourSavedValue = sp.getInt("your_string_key", defaultValue);
//defaultValue mean if there is no value with that key, it will return defaultValue.
```

If you'd like to learn more about it [here](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/data-storage/shared-preferences.html) you can get more information.

Answer to your new updated question:

As you can see my answer there is defaultValue.

```
// Restore preferences
    SharedPreferences settings = getSharedPreferences(PREF_FILE, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    Set<String> tempSet = settings.getStringSet(FIRST_LIST, "");
    Set<String> temp2Set = settings.getStringSet(SECOND_LIST, "");
    //if it is first time it will return null. So your app going crash. To avoid that make a default value. Like this.
    for (String str : tempSet)
        firstList.add(Uri.parse(str));
    for (String str : temp2Set)
        secondList.add(Uri.parse(str));
```

Comment: Thanks Eren. I've updated my question/code. Please take a look

Comment: I updated my answer also. If it's solve your problem please accept this answer.

Comment: The only difference I can tell is the `""` instead of `null`. How does this make a default value?

Comment: Second parameter is mean default value. If the function not funding anything it will return your default value. When it is null, if you start first time you will get null. If you put a value that you can handle like "" or "empty" you can avoid this. You can check here: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.html#getString

Comment: No it didn't. I went with another route to fix my problem

Comment: Can you share us your solution?

Comment: I posted my solution. You're explanation of default did help me come to it so thank you. 

In your solution, the line `Set<String> tempSet = settings.getStringSet(FIRST_LIST, "");` and the one after, `" "` is not of type `Set<String>`, so it didn't work. `null` is the correct default value to pass. Solution was simply to add conditions.

Comment: @ImagineThat If you truly understand the meaning of what is default value you can explore by yourself how to use conditions. I explain all the things and you ask another question and you pick another answer and that answer was you. OMG shocked :D. I will report you.